# Insert/Update DataTable to SQL Server ERROR:Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have tried the following solution to try to do the insert/update data table into sql server, but some problems happended. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/SqlBulkCopy--Bulk-Insert-records-and-Update-existing-rows-if-record-exists-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

1. I created a table: People

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People](
  [ID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
  [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [Country] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

2. Create a user-defined table type : PeopleType

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[PeopleType] AS TABLE(
  [ID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
  [Name][varchar](50) NULL,
  [Email][varchar](50) NULL
)
```

3. I try to use this table type to create a procedure:Update_People

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_People]
      @tblpeople PeopleType READONLY
    AS
    BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      MERGE INTO People p1
      USING @tblpeople p2
      ON p1.ID=p2.ID
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET p1.Name = p2.Name
            ,p1.Email = p2.Email
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT VALUES(p2.ID, p2.Name, p2.Email);
    END
```

but when I try to use the user-defined table type to create the procedure, An SQL server Error happened.

> "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Did I do anything wrong or miss something?

Comment: `INSERT VALUES(p2.ID, p2.Name, p2.Email);` where is Country?

Comment: I just want to insert ID,  Name, Email into People table, not all columns. So I only defined ID,  Name, Email  as a user-defined table type.

Comment: Try `INSERT VALUES(p2.ID, p2.Name, p2.Email, DEFAULT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Insert` statement to this if you don't want to add Countries:

```
INSERT INTO People(Id, Email, Name) VALUES(p2.ID, p2.Name, p2.Email);
```

The reason you receive the error is because you don't specify which columns to use the `Insert` statement expects 4 as 4 are defined in the table. But ou only provide 3.

The other option is to add the Country Property to your user defined type and add the country with the procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[PeopleType] AS TABLE(
  [ID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
  [Name][varchar](50) NULL,
  [Email][varchar](50) NULL,
  [Country][varchar](50) NULL
)

INSERT VALUES(p2.ID, p2.Name, p2.Email, p2.Country);
```

**EDIT**: I am not sure about the syntax, since I haven't used this in a while, but it could be that you only need to provide the column names like this:

```
INSERT (Id, Email, Name) VALUES(p2.ID, p2.Name, p2.Email);
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help